# PHP CURL with get form and captcha data

Tags: php, forms, curl, captcha, send

I want to access this site with curl: http://www.ttrehber.turktelekom.com.tr/trk-wp/IDA2

I'll only enter Name, Surname and Security Code data.

My questions/problems are:

1- I'll enter captcha data by hand but I have to access the page at the same time I retrieve the image data. So I can't pre enter the code. But I can't access the page to seperate times because code changes every time. So I have to access page, send captcha data to myself (I've covered that) and return the response to curl form data.

2- Form is in GET form, and it sends data with javascript. The 'BUL' image sends the form with javascript code: `"javascript:DoSearch()"`

```
function DoSearch() {
  with ( document.sForm )
  {
    if ( CheckInput() ) // bcp ok
    {
        ACTION.value="search";
    submit();
    }
  } // with
}
```

How can I make this by PHP curl?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: 1. fetch url with curl (cookie enabled) / 2. Show form to your user / 3. Submit form with all the fields to url in form action="" (same cookies as before)

Comment: Firefox: Ctrl+Shift+P Opera: Ctrl+Shift+I for opening webdeveloper console where you get to see what request is made by your browser after you press Bul button. Examine that, it will make your life easier. It is the most basic of requests. A GET one.